# Disadvantages of Running in Night after dinner

Tags: exercise, body-fat

I want to reduce my waist size and I don't get much time in morning to run, so I am planning to run after dinner for 30 - 40 minutes.... My age is 26.

Is there any disadvantages of running in night after dinner?

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: Why not run before dinner? You can eat a small meal while cooking dinner, then go for run and then eat dinner. Otherwise you'll need to wait quite some time after dinner before it's safe to run (assuming that dinner is going to be a large meal) or you'll run the risk of vomiting and even fainting due to the effects mentioned in Jagan's answer.

Comment: @CountIblis thanks,  i felt i will be tired if i run without taking dinner, as you said, i will eat little and than run and will do complete dinner.....

Comment: That's what I usually do, it works great. And eating a bit more during lunch will also help.

Comment: @CountIblis  i heard eating little food 6 times instead of 3 times is better..... Yes from now i will take bit more at the time of lunch......

Comment: Indeed, I actually eat 6 times per day, but I do eat a very large dinner. Thing is that the one hour of running I do burns a thousand Kcal or more (depending on your weight) so, you'll need to eat a lot. Even though you want to lose weight now, at some point you'll reach your desired weight and then you'll need to eat as much as you burn.

Comment: @CountIblis sure than i will eat more in night, one more thing is other than my waist, all my body parts are thin :) still i will run to reduce my waist .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immediately after dinner - No. The body is re-directing a significant amount of blood to your stomach region to deal with the dinner you just had.

Therefore, a run would not be advisable.

You should ideally wait at least 2 hours after dinner and if the dinner was heavy, at least 4 hours to allow for the food to be digested.

Short answer: Wait for 2 to 4 hours after dinner before you run.

Comment: Thanks , than i will cut my sleeping hours  & try to make some time in morning before breakfast.... :)

Comment: This answer has no citations at all to prove this claim, which is very nonspecific. Why would a run not be advisable? Would the OP fail to lose weight? Be injured or damaged in some way? Find running more difficult than it otherwise would be? This is not really an answer at this point, it needs details and references to be one.

Comment: @USer345738380 I don't advise cutting sleeping hours either.  Ensuring adequate sleep is a component of weight management (sleep quality/quantity is part of our hospital system's weight mgmt clinic intake form, and we routinely send people for sleep studies based on STOPBANG scores...)  Perhaps go to bed earlier to accommodate morning runs.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Thanks , i will try to do 8 hours :)